# Command not found

Tags: android

I am using ubuntu and am trying to build a project. I am using the following code:

```
cd tess
 cd tess-two
ndk-build
android update project --path .
 ant release
```

When I type (android update project --path) it returns (android:command not found). The ndk-build was successful.Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `android` is a tool under the Android SDK `tools` directory. You didn't add the path to your `%path%` (Windows) or `PATH` (*NIX), so the command not found.

You should install Android SDK firstly, then

For Windows, add `%android_sdk%\tools` to `%path%`

For *NIX, add `$ANDROID_SDK/tools` to `PATH`